# Continue to next result if Index out of range SwiftyJSON & AlamoFire

Tags: swift, alamofire, swifty-json

I currently have a list of file names that I'm inserting into a `Alamofire.request` to eventually `.append` the `"videoId"` from the JSON file from Youtube. When I hardcode search queries into the list that I know will result in video results it works great. But unfortunately some of the file names in the list don't find any videos. this results in `fatal error: Index out of range` I'm hoping to find a way to continue to the next item in the list when a `"videoId"` isn't available. I've experimented with `else`, `continue`, ect but could never get it right. so this example has no attempt to iterate past a bad search

I'm new to coding so feel free to change whatever if I'm completely off.

Here's my code. This is inside of my function that also gets my desired file names and inserts them into a `[String]`

```
for i in testList {

    Alamofire.request("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?key=\(API_Key)&part=snippet&q=\(i)%20Music%20Video&maxResults=1&type=video&order=relevance").responseJSON { (response)  in

        print("Result: \(response.result)")
            var json = JSON(response.result.value as Any)
        print(json)

        if let _ = json["items"].array{


                    if json["items"].arrayValue[0]["id"].exists(){
                        let songPath = json["items"].arrayValue[0]["id"]
                        let videoIdPath = songPath["videoId"].stringValue
                        var arrayOfVideos = ""


                        arrayOfVideos.append(videoIdPath)
                        print(arrayOfVideos)
                        videoArray += [arrayOfVideos] }
```

This is the YouTube Request response for context

```
Result: SUCCESS
{
  "items" : [
    {
      "etag" : "\"95M1zlW0txkV42I4OG1Zscxrg5A\/TwSmd4IGGf1uBi-y10rCaZ53JsU\"",
      "kind" : "youtube#searchResult",
      "id" : {
        "kind" : "youtube#video",
        "videoId" : "9jfhlttiQws"
      },
      "snippet" : {
        "thumbnails" : {
          "default" : {
            "url" : "https:\/\/i.ytimg.com\/vi\/9jfhlttiQws\/default.jpg",
            "width" : 120,
            "height" : 90
          },
          "high" : {
            "url" : "https:\/\/i.ytimg.com\/vi\/9jfhlttiQws\/hqdefault.jpg",
            "width" : 480,
            "height" : 360
          },
          "medium" : {
            "url" : "https:\/\/i.ytimg.com\/vi\/9jfhlttiQws\/mqdefault.jpg",
            "width" : 320,
            "height" : 180
          }
        },
        "channelId" : "UCdWVO7O7stk7MNKVARRV8rw",
        "title" : "LUAM - Clockwork Indigo (The Flatbush ZOMBiES + The Underachievers) (LYRICS)",
        "publishedAt" : "2014-10-19T01:37:31.000Z",
        "description" : "LUAM by clockwork Indigo consisting of Beast Coast rap groups Flatbush ZOMBiES & The Underachiever off of their collaborative Debut Mixtape \"Clockwork ...",
        "liveBroadcastContent" : "none",
        "channelTitle" : "JayMendezTv"
      }
    }
  ],
  "kind" : "youtube#searchListResponse",
  "nextPageToken" : "CAEQAA",
  "regionCode" : "US",
  "pageInfo" : {
    "resultsPerPage" : 1,
    "totalResults" : 10073
  },
  "etag" : "\"95M1zlW0txkV42I4OG1Zscxrg5A\/KIryoSi8eZnM0UdfR0ZqyaHGB_k\""
}
9jfhlttiQws
```

Answer (score 0):

No one answered my question but luckily I found the solution myself. When a Youtube result is not found the `"items"` array will be empty because there will be no `"videoId"` to be found. So all I had to do was add an `if` statement to my code like so

```
  if let items = json["items"].array{
if items.isEmpty{
                    return
                }
                else {
```